# Dealing with identical MAC addresses on multiple interfaces in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

In it's factory mode a tp-wdr3600 has a fixed mac-address (all of them have the same). recently they've changed to a newer u-boot that seems to continue sending out ethernet frames while the flash is being modified.

The required communication is a tftp 'get'-request to a fixed address(from fixed ip and mac).

What is the best way to deal with the identical mac-addresses?

My best idea so far is, with multiple physical interfaces, connecting one router, assigning the ip address, and binding a tftp-server to each.
(p.s. diy tftp-server - no restriction of atftp or tftpd)

UPDATE:
I ended up using linux-netns. They offer individual ARP-tables, which is exactly what i need. Communication with the outside world is possible using virtual ethernet devices. My solution uses IP-routing and a dnsmasq (DNS/DHCP/TFTP) running in each namespace.

Comment: i had another idea: netns.
will report back once i can say it's any use